Text not displaying in certain applications
The problem seems to only happen in softwares that have the same type of UI. I don't know what that UI is called, but the images below show what I am talking about. This is an image of my extensions manager: Extensions Manager
As you can see, tons of parts are missing.  This also happens with the Epiphany web browser: Epiphany. I have written some text in the search bar, but it does not show up. It does, however, show up when the window isn't in focus. But I can't capture this with a screenshot, as the text disappears when I enter screenshot mode.
These are the fixes that I have tried so far: 
Alt+f2 and then typing r 
Restarting my computer 
sudo fc-cache -r , sudo fc-cache -f and sudo fc-cache
This is my PC-information:
OS: Zorin OS 16.3 x86_64 
Host: MS-7C75 2.0 
Kernel: 5.15.0-107-generic 
Packages: 3088 (dpkg), 111 (flatpak) 
Shell: bash 5.0.17 
Resolution: 1920x1080, 1920x1080 
DE: GNOME 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: ZorinBlue-Dark 
Theme: ZorinBlue-Dark [GTK2/3] 
Icons: ZorinBlue-Dark [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: Intel i7-10700K (16) @ 5.100GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB 
Memory: 3983MiB / 23948MiB \

@Ajay Yes it does! Extensions manager works now, but the epiphany browser still doesn't work. It did improve though, as there is now text in the search bar, but nothing else appears. It's not that big of a deal though, since I don't use that browser. I tried to update my drivers, though, and that did fix it too, but it caused stuttering issues and it couldn't detect my second monitor so I went back to my old drivers. The GSK_RENDERER=gl fix is sufficient, for now at least. Thank you!
